Shell script doesn't recognize Python even after setting its path
I'm having trouble calling Python code from a shell script on Ubuntu. First of all, I confirm that Python is installed:
username@Ubuntu22:~/Documents/Script$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']


I set the Python installation path by adding a line below to the .bashrc file:
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3.10

I'd like to run a simple shell script:
#!/bin/bash
python hello.py

by running ./ex_python_shell.sh but it gives me an error message:
./ex_python_shell.sh: line 2: python: command not found

Could you advise me what I'm doing wrong?

What does type python say? if it's an alias, remember that aliases aren't expanded by default in shell scripts. To avoid ambiguity, it's probably best to specify python3 in any case - see also python-is-python3 package in Ubuntu 20.04 - what is it and what does it actually do?

@steeldriver It says, "python is aliased to python3" so we are covered on that part!

@kos, which python doesn't return anything...

Yeah I didn't see steeldriver's comment which basically addressed the same concern I had, so I removed my comment, but the culprit is: python works in an interactive shell because it's aliased to python3, however aliases are not available in scripts. Let me find the dupe

Check the question which this question has been closed as a dupe of, it addresses various ways of fixing the problem

@kos @streeldriver, Thank you for your comments! Actually, replacing python with python3 solves the problem.

Although I agree with steeldriver in that best would be to just invoke python3 instead of python.

Run the command sudo apt install python-is-python3. Then you can just call python.
